# make simpler way for if condition for java android

Tags: java

I am trying to change marker colours depends on category id in google map
Is there any cleaner way to make condition?

```
                for (int i=0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
                LatLng place = new LatLng(response.body().get(i).getLatitude(), response.body().get(i).getLongitude());

                if(response.body().get(i).getCategory().equals("1")){
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(place)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
                            .title(response.body().get(i).getName())
                            .snippet(response.body().get(i).getCategory()))
                            .setTag(response.body().get(i).getSlug());
                }
                else if(response.body().get(i).getCategory().equals("2")){
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(place)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW))
                            .title(response.body().get(i).getName())
                            .snippet(response.body().get(i).getCategory()))
                            .setTag(response.body().get(i).getSlug());
                } else {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(place)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))
                            .title(response.body().get(i).getName())
                            .snippet(response.body().get(i).getCategory()))
                            .setTag(response.body().get(i).getSlug());
                }
```

Something like this?

```
.position(place)
if(condition) {
 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))
}
...
```

Comment: use a switch - case block

Comment: @Stultuske Okay! I will try to use it. I am still learning basic java.

Comment: Since all the rest seems to be the same, why not `WhatEverIconClass icon; switch(category) { case "1": icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE); break; ...}` and then just `... .position(place).icon(icon)...`?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your advice. I am learning basic java so Your advice is very helpful.

Comment: @wwwrrrxxx if you are still learning basic java, start with that, don't try to write (android) applications. Your code is not the kind of code someone who's "still learning basic" should be working on

Comment: @Stultuske Yes. I am a javascript and php developer.

Comment: @wwwrrrxxx might be, but we're not talking about javascript or php here. You are trying to write quite advanced Java code, while you yourself state that you're just starting to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should look up for following to optimize your conditions:

1. repeating set of code inside all conditions.
2. repeating set of condition part in all conditions.

So, if I follow above in your code below always remains same:

```
.title(response.body().get(i).getName())
                            .snippet(response.body().get(i).getCategory()))
                            .setTag(response.body().get(i).getSlug());
```

Also, in your condition you always repeat `response.body().get(i).getCategory()`. Hence, if both could be extracted out your code will be way more readable and concise.

See below, how

```
String category = response.body().get(i).getCategory();
BitmapDescriptorFactory bitmapColor = null;//or your default color

   if("1".equals(category )){
           bitmapColor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE;    
    }
   else if("2".equals(category )){
            bitmapColor  = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW;                    
   } else {
           bitmapColor  = BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE;
   }

 mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(place)    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(bitmapColor))
                            .title(response.body().get(i).getName())
                            .snippet(response.body().get(i).getCategory()))
                            .setTag(response.body().get(i).getSlug());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Map<String, Float>` that maps your categories to hues. Then retrieve values from it or return a default value.

```
Map<String, Float> hueMapping = new HashMap<>();
hueMapping.put("1", BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE);
hueMapping.put("2", BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW);
```

Then instead of the whole `if-else` construct, you can just write:

```
for (int i=0; i < response.body().size(); i++) {
    YourObject obj = response.body().get(i); // Replace YourObject with the type you're getting here
    LatLng place = new LatLng(obj.getLatitude(), obj.getLongitude());
    float hue = hueMapping.getOrDefault(obj.getCategory(), BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE);

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(place)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(hue))
        .title(obj.getName())
        .snippet(obj.getCategory()))
        .setTag(obj.getSlug()
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I will try to implement your code.